# SF short story NOT by Asimov, ends with "Let there be light!"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am trying to re-find an sf short story I read in a compilation paperback some 50 years ago. No memory now of compilation title, story title or author! But it did make a notable impression on me then and I copied it out but have long since lost it.
It ends with "Let there be light!" and is NOT THE ASIMOV STORY. This story is about the Creation (Asimov's is about Re-Creation if you like) and concerns an inchoate intelligence existing in endless nothingness who sets about planning what to do about its loneliness.
Tinkle any bells anyone?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure you're referring to the Bible. The bit you want is the first anthology story.

Comment: One of these maybe? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_there_be_light#In_literature

Comment: I'm reasonably sure you're referring to the song _Hide and Seek_ by Howard Jones.

Comment: I immediately thought of "the Last Question", but you said it wasn't Asimov, so I'm stumped.

Comment: There is of course Dark Star http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069945/?ref_=nv_sr_1 - not sure though if that was based on a book.

Comment: This story was in an anthology of SciFi stories . I had a copy for years and now can't find it. I think Asimov's name was on the front cover.

Answer (score 24):

[Eric Frank Russell's](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?51) short short story, ["Sole Solution"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?67025).

Last lines:

> The time was now. The experiment must begin.
>
> Leaning forward, he gazed into the dark and said, ‘Let there be light.’
>
> And there was light.